# Create subplots from various tables using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 6 data sets from 2011-2016 based on crimes. I have extracted one column called 'Priority' which can only have a value of 1 or 2. this is basically to say a crime is either of priority 1 or 2. I have created a separate table from each data set in order to count the priorities in each data set.

```
    Priority  Count in 2011
1       1.0          36699
2       2.0         143314

   Priority  Count in 2012
0       1.0          41926
1       2.0         145504

   Priority  Count in 2013
1       1.0          43171
2       2.0         144859

   Priority  Count in 2014
0         1          42773
1         2         144707

   Priority  Count in 2015
1         1          42418
2         2         150162

   Priority  Count in 2016
0       1.0          24555
1       2.0          86272
```

I wish to produce a 3x2 `subplot` which is a bar chart type. I know how to do one but when I have tried to produce all 6 together, there have been errors.

I have been googling away how to do this and have come across the `matplotlib` website (https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html) which guided me towards a piece of code of which I adapted to be:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 2)
plt.set_title('2011 Priority Counts')
axs[0, 0].pri_2011.plot.bar()
axs[0, 0].xlabel('Priority Type')
axs[0, 0].ylabel('Reported crimes')

    .
    .
    .

plt.set_title('2016 Priority Counts')
axs[3, 2].pri_2016.plot.bar()
axs[3, 2].xlabel('Priority Type')
axs[3, 2].ylabel('Reported crimes')
plt.show()
```

Which produces many errors, such as:
`"AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_title'"`, 
`"AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'pri_2011'"`,
etc.

I had thought to include 'pri_2011' in the command to make it the first graph in the position [0, 0] of the subplot being on the to left, which would be from the first table. 'pri_2016' would be in the bottom right position of the subplot being the last graph to show.

Can anyone guide me on the correct way to do this?

Comment: You could do so without separating them into different tables.

Comment: But they are originally uploaded from different data sets?

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
axes = plt.subplots(3,2)
list_df = [df1,df2,...]

for df, ax in zip(list_df, axes):
    df.plot.bar(x='Priority', ax=ax)
    ax.label(...)
    ...
```

You could do so without separating them into different tables. For examples:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 36699, 41926,43171,42773,42418,24555],
    [2, 143314, 145504, 144859, 144707, 150162, 86272]
],
columns=['Priority']+[f'Count in {x}' for x in range(2011,2017)]
)

df.plot.bar(x='Priority', subplots=True, layout=(3,2));
```

gives:

[image]

Comment: That works - thanks! How would I increase the size of the plots so they're not squashed together?

Comment: `axes = plt.subplots(3,2, figsize=(12,9))` change `figsize` to your need.